# WIneskin wont emulate iso

Tags: macos, wrapper, wine

I'm trying to play an old game on wineskin. But it needs the CD to be inserted / emulated to run. There is no NO-CD patch for this game (Last Call - That one you play as a bartender).

I have read that you have to set wine to emulate the iso right after launching the app.

WineskinStartupScript

```
hdiutil mount "$CONTENTSFOLD/Resources/drive_c/LASTCALL.iso"
```

and

WineskinShutdownScript and WineskinQuitScript

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/LASTCALL
```

But the game will still say the cd is not inserted. Am I doing anything wrong?

I'm on OS X Lion, By the way...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not working, but there is a easier way: Create a drive_d in Wineskin, and copy all the content of the ISO file to the drive_d folder.

Creating a drive_d is difficult to new users, so probably you would prefer to create it using [Gamma Studio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gammastudio/). That probably is going to work.